# Add horizontal scroll to code box

Tags: css, scroll, blogger

I have a codebox on my blog in which I add `HTML` / `CSS` / `Javascript` codes

My CSS code looks like this:

```
.post blockquote {
    background-image: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/76401970/All%20Blogger%20Tricks/Images/blockquote.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat repeat;
    border-color: #DDDDDD #666666 #666666 #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Consolas,'Courier New',Monaco,Courier,monospace;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 45px;
}
```

Whenever I add a big code (single line). The code gets to the next line but I want the code to be in the same line and a horizontal scroll under the box. I have tried `overflow: auto` `overflow-x: scroll` `overflow-y: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [live example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow) on W3SCHOOLS.

as you can see.. you need to specify a `width` and `height`.. that is why your code does not work

adding to that, use : `white-space: nowrap;` so you can make your code in a single line

take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssps3/) for your code